# print a specific div using javascript code

Tags: javascript, image, printing

I'm trying to make a printing code in javascript (ASP.NET)
I use this code to print specific div :

```
<script>
        function CallPrinting(temp) {

            var prtContent = document.getElementById(temp);
            var WinPrint = window.open('', '', 'letf=400px,top=100px,width=800px,height=500px,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,status=0,');
            WinPrint.document.write(prtContent.innerHTML);
            WinPrint.document.close();
            WinPrint.focus();
            WinPrint.print();
            WinPrint.close();
        }

    </script>

<div id="print">
<img src=" [some source] " alt="" />
</div>
<asp:button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="print" OnClientClick="CallPrinting('print')" />
```

I make a template to some paper and I need to print it ... put the problem is with the image it didn't appear in the printing ... the 'alt' appear as alternative

any suggest ?

Comment: Is the `src` attribute a relative pathname? That won't work in the popup window, because it doesn't have the same base URL. You need to add a `<base>` tag to the window.

Comment: could you give me more detail about <base>

Comment: `<base href="URL">` sets the URL that's used to resolve relative URLs in the document. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

Comment: didn't work with me because i used more than one image path so the design is broken when i use <base > 
so I need another solution

Comment: Not sure why multiple images should be a problem. In the original page, they're all interpreted relative to the URL of the page. The point of the `<base>` tag is to all URLs in the new page to be interpreted the same way.

Comment: mmm sorry i used a wrong word ... I mean multiple path 
like i got a path ../Images/ and aap_theme/theme1/img/

and the picture is in the first path if i used a <base > 
so I will lose all the images of the design in the img folder 

but I heard about something called MapPath ... Did you know anythink about it ?

Comment: The URL in `<base>` should be the URL of original web page, not the URL of any of the images.